# How to find out if a column is an auto increment field in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, metadata, primary-key, sqlplus

How to find out if a column is an auto increment field in oracle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. Oracle doesn't have auto-increment fields.

Oracle supports *sequences*, which are separate database objects for generating numbers. These seuqences can be used in the insert statement or in a before insert trigger to generate a primary key value for the new record.

The fields themselves are just normal field and there is no relation between the sequence and the field.

So the only hope is to parse a trigger and see if you can find evidence of it being filled there using a sequence. That would be a tough job, though, and I doubt if you can make this reliable enough. After all, the trigger could fire a function which returns the value, so you have to go all the way if you want to be sure.

Comment: If there even is a trigger. Often this is done in application code (in the INSERT statement).

Comment: select trigger_name,trigger_type,status from dba_triggers where table_name = 'nameofyourtable' order by status, trigger_name

Comment: @Thilo, very well possible, but even harder to name it an 'auto incremental' field then. :)

Comment: possibly all inserts are done by a stored procedure using a sequence, that yields clearly an auto incremental field

Comment: Actually it is perfectly simple to find whether a given trigger uses a sequence.  Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730043/find-if-column-has-a-sequence/1730144#1730144  But I agree it is harder to see which column is populated with the sequence value

Answer (score 4):

As of Oracle 12.1 identity columns (with self generated sequences) can be identified by looking at the "DATA_DEFAULT" column of view DBA_TAB_COLUMS (or USER_TAB_COLUMNS or ALL_TAB_COLUMNS).
They will look like "#OWNER"."ISEQ$$_nnnnn".nextval